# How to set only 1 specific sizing border edge?

Tags: delphi, border, delphi-7, formborderstyle

I have some tool-panels made via forms with `bsSizeToolWin` borders, i have custom handling of window-movement and custom routines for sticking/aligning tool-panels with borders of main form (almost like docking functionality), but the problem that with `bsSizeToolWin` border-style i have all the corners/sides of border sizeable.

Is it possible to make only one specific border-side sizeable?
(e.g. when tool-panel sticked to left border of main form i want only right border of panel sizeable, cuz top and bottom coords of panel getting aligned according to height of client area of main form and left coord sticked to right border of main form)

Comment: Why not use a splitter?

Comment: Well it's ok to use splitter with docked forms, but not in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a *visual* standpoint, by default if a window has sizable borders then *all* edges are drawn sizable, otherwise *none* of them are, there is no in-between as the Win32 API has no concept of per-edge border styles, only whole-window border styles. If you want the various borders to look different, you would likely have to custom-draw the borders manually by handling the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` and `WM_NCPAINT` messages directly.

From a *functional* standpoint, it is fairly easy to prevent the user from resizing the window on specific edges.  The simplest way is to have the panel handle the `WM_NCHITTEST` message.  Give the panel normal sizing borders (custom drawn if desired), and then have it pass any received `WM_NCHITTEST` message to the default handler first, and then adjust the result as needed.  The benefit of this approach is that the OS will not allow the user to grab any edge that is reported as `HTBORDER` (non-sizable border), and there will be no visual feedback that the edge is resizable (even if it really is).

For instance, let's use your panel-aligned-on-the-left example.  If the default handler returns either `HTBOTTOM`, `HTBOTTOMLEFT`, `HTLEFT`, `HTTOPLEFT`, or `HTTOP`, return `HTBORDER` instead. If the default handler returns `HTBOTTOMRIGHT` or `HTTOPRIGHT`, return `HTRIGHT` instead. Otherwise return whatever the default handler returned.

Adjust the values as needed based on which edge of your Panel you want to be sizable.

For example:

```
type
  TMyPanelForm = class(TForm)
  private
    fWhichSideCanBeResized: TAlign;
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end;

procedure TMyPanelForm.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case fWhichSideCanBeResized of
    alLeft:
    begin
      case Message.Result of
        HTBOTTOM, HTBOTTOMRIGHT, HTRIGHT, HTTOPRIGHT, HTTOP:
          Message.Result := HTBORDER;
        HTBOTTOMLEFT, HTTOPLEFT:
          Message.Result := HTLEFT;
      end;
    end;
    alRight:
    begin
      case Message.Result of
        HTBOTTOM, HTBOTTOMLEFT, HTLEFT, HTTOPLEFT, HTTOP:
          Message.Result := HTBORDER;
        HTBOTTOMRIGHT, HTTOPRIGHT:
          Message.Result := HTRIGHT;
      end;
    end;
    alTop:
    begin
      case Message.Result of
        HTLEFT, HTBOTTOMLEFT, HTBOTTOM, HTBOTTOMRIGHT, HTRIGHT:
          Message.Result := HTBORDER;
        HTTOPLEFT, HTTOPRIGHT:
          Message.Result := HTTOP;
      end;
    end;
    alBottom:
    begin
      case Message.Result of
        HTLEFT, HTTOPLEFT, HTTOP, HTTOPRIGHT, HTRIGHT:
          Message.Result := HTBORDER;
        HTBOTTOMLEFT, HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
          Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure TMyPanelForm.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Result of
    HTLEFT:
      if fWhichSideCanBeResized <> alLeft then
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
    HTRIGHT:
      if fWhichSideCanBeResized <> alRight then
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
    HTTOP:
      if fWhichSideCanBeResized <> alTop then
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
    HTBOTTOM:
      if fWhichSideCanBeResized <> alBottom then
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
    HTTOPLEFT:
      case fWhichSideCanBeResized of
        alTop: Message.Result := HTTOP;
        alLeft: Message.Result := HTLEFT;
      else
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
      end;
    HTBOTTOMLEFT:
      case fWhichSideCanBeResized of
        alBottom: Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
        alLeft: Message.Result := HTLEFT;
      else
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
      end;
    HTTOPRIGHT:
      case fWhichSideCanBeResized of
        alTop: Message.Result := HTTOP;
        alRight: Message.Result := HTRIGHT;
      else
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
      end;
    HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
      case fWhichSideCanBeResized of
        alBottom: Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
        alRight: Message.Result := HTRIGHT;
      else
        Message.Result := HTBORDER;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Well about visual standpoint - i dont think that this 1 pixel difference in width of an edge really matters =) Ando i also digged a bit in NC* messages - and i see that it wouldn't be hard to make your own sizing handling thru these messages, and so u dont need native sizeable borders at all =)

Comment: If you disable the native sizable borders and then try to fudge `HTBORDER` to `HTLEFT/RIGHT/TOP/BOTTOM` based on the mouse coordinates within the window, it won't actually allow resizing since the borders were not resizable to begin with. In other words, you can prevent a sizable border from resizing, but you can't allow resizing of a non-resizable border. Unless you are planning on manually tracking mouse activity to resize the window manually with a simulated drag. Which is more work.

Comment: I meant that there are NC* messages for mouse moves and clicking/down/up - and with handling of all these messages by your own it's possible to make your own sizing routines.

Comment: Perhaps, but that is more work to accomplish the same thing the OS already handles for you.

Comment: Made QA-post on this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297215/how-to-make-custom-sizing-for-window-with-non-sizeable-borders